# Accountcode not seen in Asterisk Stasis application

Tags: java, asterisk

I have a java stasis application on Asterisk 14 using ari4java. It mostly works great. I am now trying to receive an external call and send it to a queue. I do following

1. Incoming call enters Stasis
2. Create bridge
3. Add first call(channel) to bridge
4. Create channel
5. Add second channel to bridge
6. Dial( secondChID, "Local/2601", 30)

All this works. But when one of the members of the queue answers, I get no event showing the number/name .

I added a subscriber to the queue device and did receive som events from the queue, but there is no way to associate that call with my original first and second call.

So I tried using accountcode. But no matter what I try, accountcode is always empty in all stasis events even if I force an accountcode in the dialplan prior of it going into to stasis.

Has anyone been able to do this using ARI?

Regards,
Sven

Answer (score -1):

You should adress that to your java lib developers. Account code is ok when it applicable. In most cases you should use actionid and uniqueids.